# prove $f^{-1}(B)=A$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am given $A_1$, $A_2 \subseteq A$ and $B_1$,$B_2 \subseteq B$. and the function $f: A \rightarrow B$

I want to prove that $f^{-1}(B)=A$.

I just assume that here one is talking about surjectiveness. How do I prove it? I will take any element from $B$ and prove that it has preimage? but rigorously how?

Comment: What do $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ have to do with the question?

Comment: @TMM, i dont know. may be this is the trick.

Comment: Are you given some other conditions like "$f(A_1) = f(A_2)$ implies $A_1 = A_2$ for each $A_1, A_2 \subseteq A$" or something similar?

Comment: @TMM, no, this is all what i am given. :(

Comment: @doniyor Regarding $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$, could it be that this is a finite sequence of problems and that they're used ahead but not in this particular instance?

Comment: @GitGud, it can be. because i have another 4 problems under this condition.

Comment: @doniyor Then ignore those subsets and prove the equality directly. As Lana points out, surjectivity has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @GitGud, oh okay. but what does this function means then  if it is not surjectivity? i v never seen a function like this

Comment: @doniyor This is true for every function. Try to prove it and hopefully that'll be clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8743/discussion-between-doniyor-and-git-gud)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a function, then $f^{-1}(B)=A$ is always true, it doesn't depend on any further assumptions.

Comment: I think that $f^{-1}(B)$ is the preimage of B under f, thus in your example $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. And no, not every function is surjective: but here we're not dealing with surjectivity at all; surjectivity would be $f(A)=B$

Comment: @doniyor : man you're a bit confused..http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjectivity
You're thinking of $f^{-1}(\{b\}) \neq \emptyset \forall b \in B$, really different (and that means surjectivity)

Comment: Type `[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjectivity)` to get [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjectivity).

Comment: Lana, thanks, sorry i was confused

Answer (score 1):

Let me formally spell this out, using a slightly different notation.

The definition is that for any $\;f : A \to B\;$ and $\;Y \subseteq B\;$,
$$
f^{-1}[Y] \;=\; \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in Y \}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
& a \in f^{-1}[B] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the above definition"} \\
& a \in A \;\land\; f(a) \in B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"using $\;f : A \to B\;$, so for every $\;a \in A\;$, $\;f\;$ returns an element of $\;B\;$"} \\
& a \in A \;\land\; \text{true} \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& a \in A \\
\end{align}
which by set extensionality proves that $\;f^{-1}[B] = A\;$.